# Repeat notification with different time

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I have created a local notification on 10:00 AM and I want to repeat the notification **based on a calculation** for the next time when the first notification triggered.

So how can I listen to the notification trigger to create the next notification?

Note: I have used `didRecieve` notification delegate but it works only if the app in the foreground I want the same thing for the background.

Answer (score 1):

time interval trigger would do it.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger

> Use a UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger object for local notifications that you want delivered at a time relative to the current time. You specify the number of seconds that must elapse before the notification fires. You can also set up the trigger to repeat at the specified interval.

Comment: I have used it but my problem is I want to repeat the notification at different times and it is based on a calculation when the notification triggered the next notification time will determine